# arraylist count

Tags: c#

hi i have more than 10 arraylist in my project, i need to compare all arraylist for their  count(same or not). here i need shortest way to find that.
am not sorting i need to find length of all arraylist count(same or not).

Comment: We need more details. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: are you trying to sort the arraylists by count? are you trying to find any arraylist that doesn't have some specific count?  this really needs more info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in an array and compare their counts:

```
private static bool CountsAreEqual(ICollection[] lists)
{
    int previousCount = lists[0].Count;
    for (int i = 1; i < lists.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lists[i].Count != previousCount)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Used like so:

```
ArrayList arr1 = GetFirstList();
ArrayList arr2 = GetSecondList();
CountsAreEqual(new[] {arr1, arr2});
```

Comment: If you change `lists` to a `params` argument then the caller can just pass in a variable number of arguments without needing to explicitly create an array.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you add all those arraylist in another arraylist and then run an iterator over it comparing length.

you have 10 variables, and you performing some task on all of them, a good candidate for a collection

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply use the .Count property to see how many elements are contained within the ArrayList?

Or are you asking for an algorithm to find out which ArrayLists out of a collection of 10 have the same number of elements contained in them?